# C# Project reference mystery

Tags: c#, .net, reference, msbuild, projects-and-solutions

Evening all; I've been given the task of preparing our codebase for migration to git. As part of those preparations, I've been removing redundant code and replacing references to checked-in DLL's with a reference to the same DLL delivered by an internal Nuget package.

I've updated the project reference and the only thing that's changed is the hint path but I'm getting a strange error while building and even stranger information while investigating!

So, please strap yourself in for some weirdness.

Firstly the reference in question (I'll point out here that this is the ONLY problem with what is a 475 project solution;  every .csproj has been updated to point to the new location)

Heres the original reference

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLTask, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=x86">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\lib\Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLTask.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

and now the updated reference

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLTask, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=x86">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\MyCompany.Client.Winforms.ThirdPartyLibraries.5.0.0\lib\net472\Microsoft.SqlServer.SQLTask.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

it should be obvious enough but to state the obvious;  only the path to the DLL has changed between the two references.

Now the issue.  MSBuild shows the following error;

[image: MSBUILD Error CS8012]

As you can see the issue is that apparently MSBUILD thinks I'm referencing version 14.0.0.0? But wait; that's not what my reference section above shows right...

To Visual Studio! specifically the properties of this reference.

[image: Assembly Reference Properties Window]

Ok, so it would seem that both MSBUILD (build from the batch file we use) and VS have for some reason both wound up resolving from the GAC.  So now the question is why.

I obviously understand that the specific version flag is why this has been allowed but not why it's occurring.

The assembly is located in the correct location;  I've had to scrub some of the path but you can assume it matches correctly with the reference (the .csproj files were updated with a script; 1000's of references were updated so I'm confident the path EXACTLY matches)

[image]

I thought perhaps an error had occurred on my part when packaging up our old \lib folder into the Nuget package, but the DLL restored into the packages folder location is identical to the original DLL. Heres some evidence to back that statement up.

Here is a DotPeek of the assembly;  it shows the name, version and architecture which all match the reference.

[image: DotPeek showing a Dot Net Assembly]

Here is the output of sn.exe (Strong Name)  showing the public key token;  which also matches the reference.

[image]

I'm at a loss and any help or ideas would be most welcome at this point.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out the assembly was blocked by windows when it was downloaded originally to my machine.

[image]

Clicking the unblock button caused the problem to go away!  Also deleting the packages folder and letting Nuget pull the package also fixed this issue (I placed the package in that folder manually after I created it;  before I pushed it to our feed)